# What is the probability that exactly one box remains empty

Tags: probability

Five identical(indistinguishable) balls are to be randomly  distributed into $4$ distinct boxes. What is the probability that exactly one box remains empty?

we can choose the empty box in $4$ ways.
We should fit the $5$ balls now into $3$ distinct boxes in $^7C_5$ ways.
The correct answer must be: $\frac37$ (mcq)
Can you tell me how should I proceed then?

Comment: choosing the empty box in 4 ways is problematic because there will be cases where more than 1 box is empty. divide your cases as follows: how many arrangements are there if there are exactly 1, 2, or 3 empty boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the empty box, and $B$ be the box containing $2$ balls and $C$ is $n-2$ boxes containing $1$ ball. So, there are $2\dbinom{n}{2}$ ways of arranging the letter sequence $ABC.....C$. Then the size of the sample is $\dbinom{n+n-1}{n}$ because it is equivalent to the number of ways of placing $n$ $0$'s and $n-1$ $1$'s in the order. So the probability is $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{\dbinom{2n-1}{n}}$.

Can you now solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution by way of an extension of the Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion (PIE).

Say that an arrangement of balls in the boxes has "Property $i$" if box $i$ is empty, for $i=1,2,3,4$.  Let $S_j$ be the total of the probabilities of all the arrangements with $j$ of the properties, for $j=1,2,3,4$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
S_1 &= \binom{4}{1} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^5 \\
S_2 &= \binom{4}{2} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)^5 \\
S_3 &= \binom{4}{3} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^5 \\
S_4 &= 0
\end{align}$$

An extension of PIE states that the probability that exactly $m$ of $N$ events will occur is
$$P_{[m]} = S_m - \binom{m+1}{m} S_{m+1} + \binom{m+2}{m} S_{m+2} - \dots \pm \binom{N}{m} S_N$$
Reference: *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Volume I, Third Edition*, by William Feller, Section IV.3.

Ours is the case $m=1$, $N=4$. So the probability that exactly one box is empty is 
$$P_{[1]} = S_1 - \binom{2}{1} S_2 + \binom{3}{1} S_3 - \binom{4}{1} S_4= \boxed{0.585938}$$

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a consideration of zero empty boxes in your solution. I'm not familiar with this solution method so excuse me if this is an obviously incorrect observation.

Comment: @PhilH The "exactly one" part of the PIE extension takes care of the non-empty boxes.  If exactly one box is empty, then the others are non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see how the previous answer came up with a solution so I did it differently.

$0$ boxes empty has $1,1,1,2$ box contents times $\frac{5!}{2!}$ ball arrangements $= \frac{4!}{3!}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!} = 240$

$1$ box empty has $1,1,3$ and $1,2,2$ box contents and $\frac{5!}{3!}$ and $\frac{5!}{2!\cdot 2!}$ ball arrangements $= (\frac{3!}{2!}\cdot \frac{5!}{3!}+\frac{3!}{2!}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!\cdot 2!})\cdot ^4C_1 = 600$

$2$ boxes empty has $1,4$ and $2,3$ box contents and $\frac{5!}{4!}$ and $\frac{5!}{3!\cdot 2!}$ ball arrangements $=(2!\cdot \frac{5!}{4!}+2!\cdot \frac{5!}{3!\cdot 2!})\cdot ^4C_2 = 180$

$3$ boxes empty has all $5$ in any one of $4$ boxes $= 4$

$P(1 \text{empty}) = \frac{600}{240+600+180+4} = \frac{600}{1024} = .58594$

Comment: You seem to have assumed that each of the arrangements listed is equally likely, which is false if each box is chosen independently and with equal probability.

Comment: @awkward Yes, thinking about it a little more something isn't right. I can't see what it is though. Randomly placing each of 5 balls into 4 boxes seems to me to be a probability of $(\frac{1}{4})^5$ for any single unique outcome. What am I missing?

Comment: First, there are $4^5$ ways to assign the 5 balls to 4 boxes, all of which we assume are equally likely.  Consider the 0 boxes empty case: 1,1,1,2 can be arranged in 4 ways.  But for each of these ways, the balls can be assigned to the boxes in $5! / 2! = 60$ ways.  Think of listing the balls from 1 to 5, then writing the number of the relevant box under the number of the ball.  For example, if we have one ball in each of boxes 1,2,3 and two balls in box 4, then there are $60$ ways to permute 1,2,3,4,4.  So the probability of 0 boxes empty is $4 \times 60 / 4^5$.

Comment: Thanks awkward. I corrected my counting errors in my answer. I did read up on inclusion/exclusion probability which is based on overlapping quantities and hence adding and subtracting overlaps due to under or over counting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Inclusion / exclusion is well worth studying, because its use greatly simplifies many problems in probability and combinatorics.